# Can I manage my SSH passphrase with osxkeychain, for git?

Tags: git, ssh

I'm trying to manage git credentials with keychain. I'm using

```
git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain
```

then do

```
% git pull                                                                                           
Enter passphrase for key '/.ssh/id_ed25519': 
Already up to date.
% git pull
Enter passphrase for key '/.ssh/id_ed25519': 
Already up to date.
%
```

Which tells me git is not remembering passwords. Is there any way to remember the passphrases?

Comment: For SSH keys you can use `ssh-agent` which will work seamlessly with git.  As far as I can tell, the credential helper in git doesn't help with ssh key passphrases (https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials)

Answer (score 1):

I confirm the credential.helper is only there to cache HTTPS credentials. It would not be used for SSH connection at all.

You can [add your key to the SSH agent](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent) in order to cache the passphrase which allows for your private key to be decrypted.